# Need help in understanding certain parts of ANOVA decomposition

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation

In order to understand the problem, I will first elaborate on the notation:

The definition of the functional ANOVA decomposition is given as follows. Let $F(x):[0,1]^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathbb{L}^2$ over $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_d)$. We can write $F(x) = f_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d f_i(x_i) + \sum_{i\neq j}f_{ij}(x_i,x_j)+\cdots$
In order to make the notation for the summation tractable, I will introduce the following multi-index notation: let $u \subseteq{1,\ldots,k}$, we denote by $x_u$, the subset of variables whose indexes are in $u$. Similarly, $x_{-u}$ indicates variables with indexes not in $u$. We can now write $F(x)$ as $F(x) = \sum_{u\subseteq\{1,\ldots,d\}} f_u(x_u)$ with $f_u$ depending only on $x_u$. For the sake of notational neatness, we write $u \subseteq d$ in place of $u \subseteq \{1,\ldots,d\}$.

[image]

**Problems**

1. Why is $f_{1,\ldots,d}(x)$ orthogonal to the closed set of functions which are additive in $u$?
2. How can lemma 1 be proved?

Comment: Whoever typed the stuff in the png file should have written $\langle f,g\rangle_w$ instead of $<f,g>_w$, and $\{f_u(x_u)\mid u \subseteq d\}$ instead of $\{f_u(x_u)| u\subseteq d\}$, and $w(x)\,dx$ instead of $w(x) dx$. $\qquad$

Comment: . . . . . as to the actual problem, maybe I'll return to that later . . . . $\qquad$